# std::for_each over a vector of non-copyable objects

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I was reading about `std::for_each` in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

> Unlike the rest of the parallel algorithms, for_each is not allowed to
>   make copies of the elements in the sequence even if they are trivially
>   copyable.

So, to me, it means that `std::for_each` does not copy-construct objects in the container and it should work fine with a container of non-copyable objects. But while trying to compile this code with VS2015:

```
   std::vector<std::thread> threads;

   std::for_each(
      threads.begin(), 
      threads.end(), 
      [threads](std::thread & t) {t.join(); });
```

the compiler complains about the cctor to be deleted:

```
Error   C2280   'std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)': attempting to reference a deleted function ...
```

What is wrong with my understanding of the mentioned quote?

Comment: Why do you need to capture the `threads`?

Comment: `for_each` isn't copying anything, but your lambda's capture block is.

Comment: Note: VS2015 is fairly old by now and great strides in standards conformance (and performance) have been made in the most recent versions.. you may want to try them out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your lambda capture block attempts to capture the whole vector by value. This is unnecessary, since the access to the elements is granted through the reference argument.

Try this:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](std::thread & t){t.join();});
```